# xubuntu: stop application window from going to the next workspace

Tags: linux, ubuntu, workspace

I am using xubuntu 17.04 with the xfce interface.

Having multiple workspaces, it seems that when I drag a window to the edge of the screen, my screen changes to the next workspace.

Is there a way to disable this ?

I tried googling this, but the settings whereabouts keep changing between ubuntu versions. I am not sure where I could disable window edge snapping in ubuntu 17.04.

Thanks!

Comment: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8851 except you wanna do the reverse :)

Comment: Thanks. Just found how to disable it - it was hard to find the checkbox!

Answer (score 8):

It seems that I can disable this behavior by unchecking the circled checkbox below:

[image]